# How To Handle An OIDC Callback With Blazor Hosted On CloudFront with an S3 Origin

Tags: blazor, openid-connect, amazon-cloudfront

We have a client side blazor app, hosted in an S3 bucket.  There is a CloudFront distribution serving the blazor app with an origin of the S3 bucket (folder).

We use Auth0, but this would apply to any OIDC.  After completing an authentication, the authenticator attempts to redirect back to the origin host (with a code).  But the "page" it redirects to "{root}/authentication/login-callback".

But to CloudFront, this is a 404.

Or when the user logouts, it redirects to "{root}/authentication/logout".

Again, this a 404.

Has anyone come up with a solution to this?  Where there's some type of redirect to get the event back in Blazor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to do default document handling in AWS, to serve index.html, when these paths are requested.

**SOMETHING TO COMPARE AGAINST**

I have an [Online SPA](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final) hosted in S3 and Cloudfront. It uses [lambda-edge extensions](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/tree/master/aws/lambda-edge/src) for a couple of tasks.

**OAUTH HANDLING**

The handling of the authorization code should be checked for on every page load. I always use the SPA root path as the login redirect URI. See [this handlePageLoad code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/app/app.tsx#L55) for how the main app checks whether the page is loading as the result of a login response.

**SPA 'BACK END' CODE**

Although SPAs are mostly static content, a certain amount of code is needed. I'd also recommend lookkng at [this AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/) on security headers.